# Create a script to save the file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating a Shell Script in which you want to save the command data to a file. The name of the file would be the name of the linux server obtained with the command hostname -f and the data would be the commands that will be executed in linux, cat example, ifconfig, etc. But I think I do not do it well, I'll give you an example. Thank you very much for your cooperation.

```
#!/bin/sh
server='hostname -f'
FILE="/root/'$server'.log"
df -hT
cd  /etc/sysconfig/
ls ip*
cat /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle ditinction betwee using ` and using '

if you do

```
server='hostname -f'
echo server
```

the result will be

> hostname -f

However if you do (and that's what you want)

```
server=`hostname -f`
echo server
```

the result will be

> pilouraspi

(because my raspberry name is pilouraspi...)

After that I think you want to store data coming from other commands into the file so

```
#!/bin/sh
server=`hostname -f`
FILE=/root/$server.log
touch $FILE
df -hT >> $FILE
ls /etc/sysconfig/ip* >> $FILE
cat /etc/hosts >> $FILE
```

or in a single command

```
#!/bin/sh
(df -hT && ls /etc/sysconfig/ip* && cat /etc/hosts) > /root/`hostname -f`.log
```

Comment: I changed what but it does not create the file. What I wanted is for it to create the file on each server that it will execute. Thanks for your time

Comment: @user1980835  I have edited the answer to include the way to create and append the file

Comment: @user1980835 please do consider accepting the answer.

Comment: yes i do, but there must be another option that is aesthetically more

Comment: What aesthetics are you looking for ? This is a strange comment ? Are you sure you formulated your issue correctly?

Comment: Yes, do not worry, I meant that everything came together and packed but I've fixed it, thank you